# Monitorar as requisições HTTP externas dentro da página

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, node.js

Bom dia senhores.

É possível monitorar as requisições de uma página?

Digo: Todos os arquivos que la forem chamados, exemplo: Css, Js, img, video, mp3, iframe...

Qualquer requisição **HTTP**.

Comment: Queres fazer isso no NodeJS? com o http nativo ou com biblioteca?

Comment: Sergio, primeiramente obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Queres dizer Node: sim, http nativo sim?

Comment: Sei um pouquinho de php e não encontrei nada prático por ali. Se tiver qualquer outra coisa que me entregue o resultado, será melhor do que tenho.

Comment: Não consigo responder tua pergunta. Apenas tenho uma url ex: http://globo.com e quero ver o que ela chama. O que seria?

Comment: Mas tanto te faz php ou node.js? sabes a diferênça entre os dois? Vais montar um novo servidor ou já tens um? Se queres saber o que uma página de outro dominio chama internamente isso não é possivel.

Comment: Dentro do php e não são arquivos server-side e sim client-side. Tudo aquilo que é passado pelo browser. Conseguimos ver isso pelo modo developer do  Chrome, mas quero automatizar isso.